# Dividing the sum of one DataFrame column with the sum of another DataFrame column yields 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame through which I would like to calculate percentages; however, when attempting to do so, python spits back either 0 or 1.

For example, columns `OIR.a1.d.bull` and `OIR.a1r1.d` are arrays filled with 1s and 0s.

```
>>> data['OIR.a1.d.bull'].sum()
653
>>> data['OIR.a1r1.d'].sum()
320
>>> den = data['OIR.a1.d.bull'].sum()
>>> num = data['OIR.a1r1.d'].sum()
>>> den
653
>>> num
320
>>> num / den
0
```

I expect to see - roughly - the following.

```
>>> num / den
0.49004594
```

Comment: works.  why?  Is it converting to an integer and rounding?

Comment: See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 0):

You do integer division so your result will be an integer, which means that the fractional part of the division's result is truncated. To get a float you have to convert one of your values to a float.

```
float(num)/den
```

Comment: Since OP is using Python 2.7 he also has the option of doing `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You are right and I considered to add this information, but maybe OP uses `/` for strict int division in other places of his code that will break when done as float division.